# SCons detects Visual C++ v14.2 (2019) but not v14.1 (2017)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, scons

I need to build a dependency that uses SCons, and I need to build it with VC++2017, because another dependency I have cannot be built with VC++2019.

SCons successfully detects VC++2019 (v14.2), but not VC++2017 (v14.1):

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\scons [...] --msvc-version=14.1 [...]
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 3.1.1
python version: 2 7 13 'final' 0

scons: warning: VC version 14.1 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
 Installed versions are: ['14.2', '14.0', '11.0']
[...]
C++ compiler $CC does not work
```

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise as well as Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, and for both, I have installed the platform tools / compiler for v14.1 and x86/x64. Compiling with the VC++2017 platform tools works fine in Visual Studio 2019 as well as using MSBuild, so the problem seems to be with SCons only.

How does SCons detect VC++2017 and VC++2019 and where should I start looking for the problem?

(There are old threads about this, but most of them are about people wondering why the "classic" detection/config methods using registry and vcvars.bat no longer work, so these are not helpful)

Comment: We modified our version SCons (2.5.1) to support 14.1. The issues were that VS no longer sets a registry key that SCons was using to detect its presence, so we added a call to `vswhere` to find it. The files to look at for this version of SCons are in `Scons/Tool/msvs.py` and in `SConst/Tool/MSCommon` look at `common.py`, `vs.py`, and `vc.py`.

Comment: @metal Thank you. I found these py files myself, and it looks like SCons always uses the default tool version (in this case VC++2019) rather than a minor version that I specify. A comment says that this is not supported "for now". Do you know if this is going to be addressed in the future? I will have to find a workaround for now anyway...

Comment: The obvious workaround of uninstalling the v14.2 platform tools from both VS2019 and VS Built Tools 2019 did not solve it, except SCons now also doesn't detect v14.2 any more. Neither did modifying `VCToolsVersion.default.txt`, which SCons seems to be parsing.

Comment: We haven't updated to 14.2 yet, so I haven't faced that. Glancing at the [SCons github](https://github.com/SCons/scons), it looks like they are buried -- 683 issues and 18 open PRs. I don't know when to expect them to update anything. (I myself much prefer other cross-platform build systems at this point. CMake isn't a panacea, but it is better than SCons for my use cases. Meson is another reasonable choice.)

Comment: @metal I have no choice in build system, as I'm building a dependency library. I would personally choose MSBuild or Visual Studio over any third-party tool any day. However, I have now found a solution that is somewhat clean and posted an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @metal - just because there are many issues and PR's doesn't mean no forward progress. 3.1.1 was just released.

Comment: @FlorianWinter - Which version of SCons are you using?

Comment: --msvc-version=14.1 is not a scons option btw. That's something implemented by whatever build system using scons has implemented.  What package are you trying to download? (pointer to project page and/or github would be useful)

Comment: Try running scons with ```set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=MSDEBUG.txt``` and then pastebin that file.

Comment: @bdbaddog https://pastebin.com/JKjiuvHs - But I have already looked at the code in SCons and the files on disk it looks at, and I know that it cannot work. SCons will always use 2019 platform tools (14.2) if VS2019 is installed, even if you uninstall 2019 platform tools. There even is a comment that says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: This is still (2021-09-16) [an issue](https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues/3664), and a simple workaround may be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62015647/2279059) - My answer also has a workaround, but it is more complicated and mostly for educational purposes on how recent versions of VC++ compilers can be detected and are (not properly) detected by SCons. You may also want to use my workaround if you are creating a build script for a build server or multiple development machines with varying setups.**

**Update: The issue in SCons is still (2023-10-23) open and still being discussed. It might still affect newer versions of both Visual Studio and the platform toolset.**

The current version of SCons does not support selecting MSVC v14.1 (aka "Visual C++ 2017") if Visual Studio 2019 is installed, but Visual Studio 2017 is not. I confirmed this by looking at the code of SCons (see below).

An alternative approach is to use the `--msvc-script` option instead of `--msvc-version`.

In the MSVC installation folder, typically `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\`, you will find a file called `vcvarsall.bat`. If you run this without arguments, you will see that you can give it arguments for target platform and tools version, e.g.,

```
vcvarsall.bat x86 10.0.17763.0 -vcvars_ver=14.1
```

to compile for x86 (32-bit), Windows SDK version `10.0.17763.0` and tools version `14.1` (Visual C++ 2017).

Once you have found a command line for `vcvarsall.bat` that suits you, put it into a new BAT file that you create, say `myvcconfig.bat` (You have to use the complete path to `vcvarsall.bat`), then use the following command-line switch to SCons: `--msvc-script=myvcconfig.bat`.

*** Notes ***

- Some parameters to SCons are redundant and will not work with `--msvc-script`, for example `--32`. SCons will tell you about them, so just remove them from the command-line.
- The installation path of Visual Studio may be different from the one I provided above. You can find the installation path using Microsoft's own [VSWhere tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Examples). See also [Locate Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/locating-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
- Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 are separate installations with separate build tools. You can detect and use the `vcvarsall.bat` files of either ones. For example, if you are setting up a toolchain for a build server, you may want to use Visual Studio Build Tools 2019. If you just want to build one library one time (as in my case), just use the Visual Studio that is installed on your dev machine.
- In case you are interested in how SCons detects MSVC and why it doesn't work, you can look at the source code in `SCons/Tool/MSCommon/vc.py`. You can clone [the SCons GIT repository](https://github.com/SCons/scons).

**UPDATE: The following comment in `vc.py` (as of 2021-09-16) shows why this is still an issue in SCons and why this workaround is needed if you have both VC2017 and VC2019 compilers installed:**

```
# make sure the cl.exe exists meaning the tool is installed
if ver_num > 14:
    # 2017 and newer allowed multiple versions of the VC toolset to be
    # installed at the same time. This changes the layout.
    # Just get the default tool version for now
    #TODO: support setting a specific minor VC version
```

[Direct link](https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/d67006f6637e8efb5a55eb80e7dd8ee36322412a/SCons/Tool/MSCommon/vc.py#L570) (valid at time of writing)

Comment: I'd quibble just slightly: "The current version of SCons does not support selecting MSVC v14.1 if Visual Studio 2019 is installed." - more accurate is "... if Visual Studio 2017 is not installed" - the granularity of vswhere is at the "product" (i.e. VS/BuildTools), not "compiler" level. Should be able to follow this at https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues/3664.

Comment: @MatsWichmann Good point. It is indeed possible that VS2017 was not installed on my system, as I am using Visual Studio 2019 and VS Build Tools 2019 with the VS2017 toolset. This is a legitimate use case, as for example you may want the improved VS2019 IDE but may have to compile with an older compiler due to dependencies. An alternative workaround MAY be to install VS2017.

Comment: Yes, agree it's a legitimate use case, scons simply doesn't yet have the code to detect the compiler in such case.

Answer (score 1):

For current scons, it will believe what it gets back from `vswhere.exe` for the versions where that tool is considered definitive - 2017 and 2019.  You can try seeing what that gives you.

```
vswhere -products * -property installationPath
```

That information is used to help locate the desired *vars*.bat file which imports the seetings needed.

Comment: I just retested, it's letting me select the version just fine.  To get 2017, try this:   env = Environment(MSVC_VERSION="14.1")

Comment: vswhere only returns the installation path of Visual Studio (or, with the right command-line parameters, probably, Visual Studio Build Tools). It doesn't give you the path to a specific platform toolset, of which there may be multiple ones. SCons indeeded uses vswhere and some more information, but will always default to the v142 platform toolset if 2019 is installed, so this does not help.

Comment: Did you test this with Visual Studio 2019 installed? Because this is where it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: A test setup here has all of VS 2017 and 2019 Comunity and 2015 Pro installed; using the MSVC_VERSION flag as indicated can successfully select any one of the three.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using the MSVC_VERSION flag"? Do I have to set an environment variable? Add code to a Python file? I tried adding `MSVC_VERSION=14.1` to the SCons command-line, but I got "unknown variables specified".

Comment: @FlorianWinter - env['MSVC_VERSION']=14.1 and/or env=Environment(MSVC_VERSION='14.1') . You can specifically request a given version. See the manpage and search for MSVC_VERSION : https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-MSVC_VERSION

Comment: @bdbaddog This does not answer my question of how I am supposed to use this variable. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: I also find it somewhat unplausible that SCons would be able to select the correct version of the platform build tools when using an environment variable, while it is unable to do so when using a command-line switch, and while there is a comment in the code that explicitly says it will default to 14.2 if 2019 is installed.

Comment: It's not a shell environment variable, it's a construction environment variable - different things.  You set `MSVC_VERSION` in the Construction Environment, but it has to happen early, before that environment is initialized or scons will already have picked the default, which is the newest found installed version.  You can hop on the scons IRC or Discord channel to discuss further, stackoverflow isn't really ideal for a back-and-forth conversation (links here: https://scons.org/contact.html)

Comment: @FlorianWinter - SCons itself has NO command line switch to select MSVC version. If the build system you're using does then the implementers have done so.  I'm talking about env=Environment(MSVC_VERSION="14.1") . This must be set before the Environment initializes it's tools. (or explicitly before initializing msvc)

Comment: @bdbaddog Fine, but if MSVC_VERSION (which I still don't know how to use) triggers the same code in SCons - which is definitely in SCons, and which I have seen, then it cannot possibly work in my setup.

Comment: @FlorianWinter here's how you use it (as I pasted above). In your SConstruct/SConscript where you create your Environment(), you add as follows env=Environment(MSVC_VERSION="14.1"), then use that env as env.Program(target,source,LIBS=...) for example. More that than if you need help please come to IRC, Discord or users mailing list

Comment: @bdbaddog It isn't my SConstruct, but someone else's. The option `--msvc-version`, which it defines, does exactly what you suggest: Set `MSVC_VERSION`, and it does not work because of code in SCons itself, which uses the 14.2 toolkit whenever vswhere says MSVC2019 is installed. A comment in SCons also says so. It is a bug / missing feature in SCons version 3.1.1.

Comment: @FlorianWinter Can you point us at the code in question? Is this a package you've downloaded?

Comment: @bdbaddog Sorry for the very late reply, but I added a reference to the code in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480060/2279059

Answer (score 1):

I have found a perfect and simple solution:

1. Open file *MSCommon/vc.py*, find line: `vc_pdir = os.path.join(vsdir[0], 'VC')`
2. Change [0] to [1]
3. Re-build, the python will use vs2017
4. The reason is: if you install multi vs versions, the vsdir[0] is the highest one

Comment: This works, but only on a system where a newer version of Visual Studio is in fact installed. It may be good enough to work around the problem on a developer's machine, but it is unsuitable as a general and reliable solution you would apply, e.g., in a build script that should automatically work correctly on any system.